Using AutoMapper to map child collection to an existing object?
I have a database class and a DTO that both have a child collection (e.g. Member/MemberDto with a collection of Email/EmailDto). When I map an incoming DTO to a new object, everything seems to work perfectly. However, when I map an incoming DTO to an existing object, the child collection does not get mapped. What am I doing wrong?
I have the following in my AutoMapper configuration:
cfg.AddCollectionMappers();
cfg.AddProfile<DtoMapperProfile>();
cfg.UseEntityFrameworkCoreModel<MyDbContext>(serviceProvider);

Whereas I can accomplish the child collection mapping with an "AfterMap", I have quite a number of these scenarios and, since I assume I'm not the first to encounter this (in fact I assume it's a fairly common problem), I assume this is already solved somewhere. Help?
I don't know if it matters, but I'm using a TPT inheritance hierarchy (i.e. Member inherits Contact, and it's Contact that actually has the child collection of Email).

Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others to provide an answer faster.
